# Receiving data from any host in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I used `MPI_Irecv` to recieve data from a certain host in MPI. By using *"rank of source"* in the input parameters of the function, I have to define which host I want to receive data from. But it is not important which host sent data to me, I just want to take data. How can I take data without defining the rank of sender?

I guess that I can make a loop which scan all "ranks" but is there any much simpler method that can take data whichever its sender is?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the program allow more than one rank to attempt to SEND data to the MPI_IRecv?  If not, then MPI_ANY_SOURCE is a good solution.  If more than one rank can send, then there is a chance of a hang with a blacking MPI_Send call...or an error at MPI_Finalize if there is an unmatched MPI_Send.  Care must be taken to cancel any unmatched MPI_Send/ISend calls...or you must be prepared to live with an error on MPI_Finalize.

Comment: Many hosts do not attempt to send data at the same time. But just curiosity, Is `MPI_Cancel` enough for cancelling?

Comment: MPI_Cancel is enough to cancel the unmatched MPI_Send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MPI_ANY_SOURCE rank which, in the various recv/probe functions, makes them accept a message from anyone.